# How to specify attributes independently of each other?

Tags: mysql

I have a 'flight` table that has a flight #, flight date, origin and destination airports, departure and arrival times as attributes. It also has an aircraft registration and route ID as foreign keys. Initially i had the flight # as a primary key but then realize that this won't work because flights does fly on different days hence it won't be unique in the table. My question is how do i specify the flight # independently of the date? For example FL909 flies on a Monday, Wednesday and Friday? Or would i have to de-allocate the flight # as the primary key

On a related note how do i attach files with a message on here? I'd love to get some feedback on my ERD.

Comment: If flight (or any other value) needs to be unique in a table, it cannot (alone) be it's primary key; if a "flight#" only makes one uh...."flight" a day, flight# and flight_date **could** be the primary key (but it sounds like you are better of with a "surrogate" id, such as an auto-increment field).

Comment: @Uueerdo. Thanks for your input. I was considering introducing an additional attribute called schedule_id and have it as the primary key and auto_increment but i'm still thinking of other options for the design of the table..